# Java 8 Streams: IntStream to String

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

In Java 8 streams API, calling `chars()` on any `String` object returns an `IntStream` object containing all the characters.

What would be the correct way to convert the returned `IntStream` object back to a `String`? Calling `toArray()` would give me an `int[]`, which is not accepted by any of the `String` constructor.

Comment: Which class contains the `chars()` method?

Comment: The method is defined in the `CharSequence` interface, which `String` implements.

Comment: `chars().mapToObj(i -> (char) i).map(String::valueOf).collect(Collectors.joining());`

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use `toArray()`, then the [`String(int[], int, int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String-int:A-int-int-) constructor. This isn't entirely satisfactory as `chars()` is specified to return UTF-16 code units, basically:

> Returns a stream of int zero-extending the char values from this sequence. Any char which maps to a surrogate code point is passed through uninterpreted.

Using [`codePoints()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/CharSequence.html#codePoints--) instead would be more in-keeping with this constructor, which expects code points rather than UTF-16 code units. Otherwise (with `chars`) if your original string *does* contain surrogate pairs, you may find you get an error - I haven't tried it, but it would make sense.

I don't know of a simple way of doing this without converting to an array first.

Comment: Okay. It seems to be safer to use `codePoints()` instead of `chars()`, although it shouldn't matter in my case because I'm just working within the ASCII range. Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 39):

using `StringBuilder`'s `appendCodePoint` method would do the trick as well,

```
IntStream in = "Convert me to a String".codePoints();

String intStreamToString = in.collect(StringBuilder::new,
        StringBuilder::appendCodePoint, StringBuilder::append)
        .toString();

System.out.println(intStreamToString);
```

Comment: Yeah, but this one also has the problem of code unit / code point mismatch @jon-skeet pointed out. The `chars()` returns the stream of _code units_, whereas `appendCodePoint` expects to get _code points_, as the name suggests.

Comment: The problem is StringBuilder object will create many times.

Comment: @Namo no, only one `StringBuilder` will be created, see [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#collect-java.util.function.Supplier-java.util.function.ObjIntConsumer-java.util.function.BiConsumer-)

Comment: @cdalxndr You're right! I was confused. The [begin method](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/stream/ReduceOps.java#L390) called only one time in TerminalOp.

Answer (score 8):

I am pretty sure there must be many ways to do it, but another way is by using a `StringWriter`:

```
IntStream in = "It was the best of times".chars();
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
in.forEach(sw::write); 
System.out.println(sw.toString());
```

This all could also be expressed in a collector as:

```
IntStream in = "It was the best of times".chars();
String text = in.collect(
    StringWriter::new, 
    StringWriter::write, 
    (swl, swr) -> swl.write(swr.toString())).toString();
System.out.println(text);
```

Comment: Haven't thought of combining it with the IO libraries. Thanks.

Comment: @nullstein It could also be written as a collector, as my edition shows, although I doubt it makes it easier to read. On the bright side, it does have better referential transparency, since the side effects are hidden from the stream user. This is ultimately similar to the StringBuilder answer, though.

Comment: Note that a StringWriter is a wrapper around StringBuffer (the synchronized version of StringBuilder) so is (relative) much slower than using StringBuilder

Answer (score 5):

This is an other idea:

```
@Test
public void testIntStreamSequential() {
    final String testString = "testmesoftly";
    IntStream is = testString.chars();
    String result = is.collect(
        StringBuilder::new,
        (sb, i) -> sb.append((char)i),
        StringBuilder::append
        ).toString();
    assertEquals(testString, result);
}

@Test
public void testIntStreamParallel() {
    final String testString = "testmesoftly";
    IntStream is = testString.chars();
    String result = is.parallel().collect(
        StringBuilder::new,
        (sb, i) -> sb.append((char)i),
        StringBuilder::append
        ).toString();
    assertEquals(testString, result);
}
```

Note that using a dedicated `Collector` as proposed by @Lii is not very efficient, because of the boxing so you should use this three argument construct (thanks @holger)

Comment: I actually thought about this direction, but it seemed too complicated for the purpose. I have a quick question, though. Why is the third parameter `(sb1, sb2) -> {}`? What exactly does this mean? Is this part not used at all? Maybe it is only relevant when using parallel streams?

Comment: It is the combiner, "A function that accepts two partial results and merges them.".  It is not used when using sequential. However my example is ugly, so i improved it and removed the warning about parallel support

Comment: `IntStream` has no support for dedicated `Collector`s, so using the three-arg `collect` method is the only choice (unless you want to box every `int`…).

Comment: @holger You are right! Edited my answer