# How to use Streams to handle Strings?

Tags: java, string, java-stream

The Java 8 methods `String.chars()` and `String.codePoints()` (which are actually inherited from [`CharSequence.chars()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/CharSequence.html#chars--) and [`CharSequence.codePoints()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/CharSequence.html#codePoints--)) are very useful to work on `char`s (as `int`s) in an `IntStream`.

However, is there any collector in the JDK that allows to convert those `int`-ed `char`s into a `String` again?

### What I tried and why they're not okay

#### `IntStream.toArray`

I guess I could use the `String(int[],int,int)` constructor, but what annoys me then is that I need to provide the third argument, which is usually unknown when I come from an `IntStream.toArray()`. But that force me to use store the resulting array into an temporary variable, which is okay if used in a specific method/collector, but not so much when used "on the fly", like the streams usually allow to.

```
String str = "zyxwvutsrqponmlkjihgfedcba";
int[] codePoints = // Seems OK if I use codePoints, but chars??
    str.codePoints()
      .filter(cp -> "aeiouy".indexOf(cp) < 0) // remove vowels
      .sorted()
      .toArray();
String result = new String(codePoints, 0, codePoints.length);
```

The confusing part here is the distinction between characters and code points, but mostly because we kind of work on `char`s all day and then nobody expects <s>the Spanish inquisition</s> a `String(int[],int,int)` constructor, especially without its `String(int[])` counterpart.

#### `IntStream.collect`

Also, the [`IntStream.collect(Supplier,ObjIntConsumer,BiConsumer)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#collect-java.util.function.Supplier-java.util.function.ObjIntConsumer-java.util.function.BiConsumer-) method seems really subpar when compared to its [`Stream.collect(Collector)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#collect-java.util.stream.Collector-) equivalent. We can't even have an `IntCollector`, which would help to create such methods. Immediately discarded.

However a solution exists:

```
String str = "zyxwvutsrqponmlkjihgfedcba";
String result = str
    .codePoints()
    .filter(cp -> "aeiouy".indexOf(cp) < 0) // remove vowels
    .sorted()
    .collect(StringBuilder::new, StringBuilder::appendCodePoint, StringBuilder::append)
    .toString();
```

Though, this is hugely verbose and unintuitive. Being able to give a `Collector` would beat this a thousand times! Also, the result of the collect is a `StringBuilder`, forcing to call `.toString()`. Yup, really not intuitive.

#### Use an intermediary `StringBuilder`

The most satisfying solution so far.

```
String str = "zyxwvutsrqponmlkjihgfedcba";
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
str.codePoints()
  .filter(cp -> "aeiouy".indexOf(cp) < 0) // remove vowels
  .sorted()
  .forEach(sb::appendCodePoint);
String result = sb.toString();
```

Using it is not obvious as I need two intermediary "solutions": firstly, use codepoints and secondly, use a `forEach` combined with `StringBuilder` instead of a `Collector` as the `Stream` API usually does.

#### Flatten as loops

The obvious solution is to flatten everything and do it "the old way" with for loops. But this fails the title as then we don't "use streams to handle strings".

Unfortunately, given the lack of other obvious tools with streams, this is still the best option to produce readable code for my colleagues.

#### Conclusion

I think I shouldn't use `String.chars()` or `String.codePoints()`, unless I missed an obvious method, hence the question: **is there any trivial/obvious way to perform simple stream operations on String characters/codePoints and return `String`s easily?**

### Notes

- I'm well aware of Guava's `CharMatcher.removeFrom` here to remove vowels, but that's not the point: the point is how to properly use the Stream API in the string context.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28280721/java-8-streams-intstream-to-string

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth Blatant duplicate, yes. I don't know why but SO's suggestions never show up appropriate similar questions when I ask them. I'll remove in a few minutes, making sure you read this.

Comment: You can leave it, so hopefully the next person to ask the question will get one of them as suggestion.

Comment: The intended purpose of the primitive stream specialization is to support operations without boxing overhead, so using the generic `Collector` directly doesn’t fit. You can use collectors, if you turn to the generic `Stream` explicitly via `.boxed()` or `.mapToObj(…)`. So you can use `String result = "zyxwvutsrqponmlkjihgfedcba".codePoints() .filter(cp -> "aeiouy".indexOf(cp) < 0) .sorted() .mapToObj(Character::toChars).map(String::new) .collect(Collectors.joining());` but it still suffers from needing a complex mapping step; boxed single-character `Stream`s simply aren’t expected to be used…