# replace specific element in a Intstream and convert the IntStream to String

Tags: java, debugging, java-stream

I am trying to replace the char 'a' with "aFbcr"and 'e' with "eFbcr" in a string .For example ,I have a string `apple`,and then I got `aFbcrppleFbcr` after replacement .

this is how I do .

```java
IntStream src ="apple".chars();
 String other = src.mapToObj(s -> {
            if (s == 97) {
                return "aFbcr".chars();
            } else if (s == 101) {
                return "eFbcr".chars();
            }
            return IntStream.of(s);
        }).collect(StringBuilder::new, StringBuilder::appendCodePoint, StringBuilder::append).toString();
```

[Java 8 Streams: IntStream to String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28280721/java-8-streams-intstream-to-string)

I have searched how to convert Intstream to String.So as above ,I decide to get an intstream and then convert it to String.but I just got this error

`'collect(java.util.function.Supplier<R>, java.util.function.BiConsumer<R,? super java.util.stream.IntStream>, java.util.function.BiConsumer<R,R>)' in 'java.util.stream.Stream' cannot be applied to '(<method reference>, <method reference>, <method reference>)'`

[image]

How I fix this to error done .Or another java stream operations for this String replacement problem

UPDATES:
I have tried some new ideas.

```java
IntStream src ="apple".chars();
        String a =src.mapToObj(s -> {
            if (s == 97) {
                return "aFbcr";
            } else if (s == 101) {
                return "eFbcr";
            }
            return String.valueOf((char) (s));
        }).collect(Collectors.joining());
        System.out.println(a);
```

it seems work,but I don't know if it has side effects >__>

Comment: @ScaryWombat I really want to do this ,but the codewars problem request me to do this  in stream operation>__>

Answer (score 4):

Instead of `mapToObj`, you should use `flatMap`, this is because your `map` operation was not sending out an `IntStream` like you were expecting, but it was sending out a `Stream<IntStream>`.

This is the reason why you could not collect in a `StringBuilder`, because it has no methods to handle `IntStream`s of course.

Using `flatMap` makes it possible to return an `IntStream` based on the concatenation of all the `IntStream` generated inside of the `flatMap` method

```
String other = src.flatMap(s -> {
    if (s == 97) {
        return "aFbcr".chars();
    } else if (s == 101) {
        return "eFbcr".chars();
    }
    return IntStream.of(s);
}).collect(StringBuilder::new, StringBuilder::appendCodePoint, StringBuilder::append).toString();

System.out.println("other = " + other); // other = aFbcrppleFbcr
```

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash voted to reopen it, saw it this morning but did not bother checking to be honest, now it's reopened by the way

Answer (score 2):

You should make two changes in your approach:

1. You can use `a` and `e` instead of `97` and `101`.
2. Use `flatMap` instead of `mapToObj` in order to flatten `Instream`s to a single `Instream` which you can collect the way you want to do.

**Demo:**

```
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String other = "apple".chars().flatMap(s -> {
            if (s == 'a') {
                return "aFbcr".chars();
            } else if (s == 'e') {
                return "eFbcr".chars();
            }
            return IntStream.of(s);
        }).collect(StringBuilder::new, StringBuilder::appendCodePoint, StringBuilder::append).toString();

        System.out.println(other);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
aFbcrppleFbcr
```

Further simplification using Ternary Operator:

```
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String other = "apple".chars()
                .flatMap(s -> s == 'a' ? "aFbcr".chars() : s == 'e' ? "eFbcr".chars() : IntStream.of(s))
                .collect(StringBuilder::new, StringBuilder::appendCodePoint, StringBuilder::append)
                .toString();

        System.out.println(other);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
aFbcrppleFbcr
```

In production code, however, you should do it using `String#replace`:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String other = "apple".replace("a", "aFbcr").replace("e", "eFbcr");
        System.out.println(other);
    }
}
```

**Otput:**

```
aFbcrppleFbcr
```

or even simpler using `String#replaceAll`:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String other = "apple".replaceAll("[ae]", "$0Fbcr");
        System.out.println(other);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
aFbcrppleFbcr
```

where `[ae]` specifies one of the characters from inside the square brackets and is known as [Character Classes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/char_classes.html) and `$0` specifies the match.